# Can PyCharm set breakpoints on ipython notebook?

Tags: python, ipython, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I'd like to know how to set breakpoints in `IPython` notebook on PyCharm.

If it's possible, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must start IPython Notebook from **Pycharm's run**

1. Find the IPython path (ex `which ipython` on linux). Copy the resulting path, we will need it!
2. On PyCharm go to Run > Edit Configuration > <kbd>+</kbd> button on top left most corner (add configuration) > Choose Python. 
   Give your configuration a name.
3. On the configuration tab, in the Script textbox, paste the path from step 1. On the script, parameters write `notebook`.
4. Apply then Ok.

This is essentially like calling `ipython notebook` from the terminal

Now place your brakepoints and run the notebook from PyCarm (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> or click the playbutton).